# Could not insert new outlet connection after I update Xcode to new version XCode 9.0 in Xamarin.IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin.ios

I've updated my XCode to latest version 9.0.
After that, I am getting error "could not insert new outlet connection..." when I try to create new outlet connection in Storyboard of my Xamarin IOS project that has been working great.

I can't find anyway to fix it.
Please help me to fix.
Thanks.

Comment: are you using xamarin's iOS designer or xcode's interface builder?

Comment: I am using xcode's interface builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that it's known issue in VS for MAC
You can find the fix here.
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58198